# Why does ::after appear for all divs?

Tags: css

I want to have a top arrow for a drawer and to do so used `::after` for the menu div. However it appears for all div inside menu div.

I have a `div` with class drawer and for that added top arrow. within drawer `div` have details `div` which contains `svg`, `span` and `div` element.

Now this css in `::after` applies to `div` within details `div` as well.

How can I fix it? I don't want it to appear anywhere else apart for the menu `div`.

Below is the code:

```css
.drawer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 392px;
  top: 55px;
  right: 8px;
  min-height: 40%;
  max-height: 450px;
  margin-left: 16px;
   ::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 83%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 14px;
    border-style: solid;
  }
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px;
  min-height: 49px;
  li {
    list-style: none;
  }
  .details {
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
    color: #333;
    margin-right: 4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="drawer">
  <ul>
    <li class="item">
      <div class="details">
        <svg/>
        <span>sometext</span>
        <div>
          <div/><img/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a working jsfiddle example. It was only applying to .drawer for me.

Comment: `&::after`? If you are using nested syntax you need `&` to have it just apply to the outer selector.